# rpm un-installs with warning unlink messages

Tags: shell, jenkins-plugins, rpm-spec

I have created a spec file which can install/upgrade/uninstall a package .But , on uninstallation , it uninstalls the package with warnings

```
warning:    erase unlink of /var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global/username.html failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global/timeOut.html failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global/remoteRootDir.html failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global/port.html failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global/password.html failed: No such file or directory
```

How can i resolve this error ? Is there any way to ignore such warning in spec file ?

Comment: Are the files there? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix I had to make to resolve the warning messages. It was caused by a `rm -rf` that was placed in the `%preun` [pre-uninstallation] section. You don't need to have any `rm -rf` in your SPEC file. RPM will implicitly and recursively delete the contents of each directory within the installation directory. So if you really want to go ahead and clean-up the empty directories left after uninstallation, add the `rm -rf <installdir>` under `%postun` section. That will take care of the warnings and will result in a clean uninstall deleting the installation directory post uninstallation. Check this article http://meinit.nl/rpm-spec-prepostpreunpostun-argument-values - describes the 4 useful tags: `%pre %preun %post %postun`

Answer (score -1):

Your RPM package tries to delete the files and folders it has put in place (implicit behavior). Now, you will get this message:

1. If someone (you or your application) deleted the containing folder in the meantime.
2. If your SPEC file explicitly deletes the folder, typically in the `%preun` section (isn't there a `rm -rf` hanging around?)

Note that I actually mean *folder*, i.e. `/var/hudson/master/plugins/publish-over-cifs/help/global` in your case. You will not get these warnings if the target file(s) are missing. In other words, try replacing the `rm -rf <path>` by `rm -rf <path>/*` in the SPEC file, if that's where you are deleting it.

Comment: Have you tried to check the trace with `rpm -e -vvvvv  <packagename>`?

Comment: Didn't know the 5 v option existed! I do happen to have a rm -rf <installdir> in the preun section. Replacing with rm -rf <installdir>/* gave me the same warning